# Using python selenium to scrape time data

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I'm using the following lines of code to get the utime of an element. From the output I can see that I'm targeting the correct area and that the utime attribute is present there, but I still recieve an output of `None`. I have tried re-writing the `data-utime` attribute several times to make sure it is formatted correctly for the function. What am I missing here?

Code:

```
   timeStampBox = post.find_element_by_css_selector('.fsm.fwn.fcg')
   timeStampBox = timeStampBox.find_element_by_class_name('_5pcq')

   print(timeStampBox.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
   print(timeStampBox.get_attribute('data-utime'))
```

Output:

```
<abbr title="Monday, September 4, 2017 at 6:11am" data-utime="1504530675" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz"><span class="timestampContent" id="js_15">September 4 at 6:11am</span></abbr>
None
```

Comment: Your code references a bunch of HTML that you have not posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `abbr` element is the `innerHTML` of `timeStampBox` *but* `data-utime` is *not* an attribute of `timeStampBox`.

Here's how I emulated your situation:

```
<html>
<body>
<div><abbr title="Monday, September 4, 2017 at 6:11am" data-utime="1504530675" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz"><span class="timestampContent" id="js_15">September 4 at 6:11am</span></abbr></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `div` element is a container for the `abbr` element. I can pretend that it's your `timeStampBox` element.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('file://c:/scratch/temp.htm')
```

Identify `timeStampBox` and get its `innerHTML`. As before I got the `abbr` element.

```
>>> timeStampBox = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div')
>>> timeStampBox.get_attribute('innerHTML')
'<abbr title="Monday, September 4, 2017 at 6:11am" data-utime="1504530675" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz"><span class="timestampContent" id="js_15">September 4 at 6:11am</span></abbr>'
```

`data-utime` is `None` because this property does not exist in `timeStampBox`.

```
>>> timeStampBox.get_attribute('data-utime')
```

But it's there in `abbr`.

```
>>> abbr = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('abbr')
>>> abbr.get_attribute('data-utime')
'1504530675'
```

Moral of our story: search directly for `abbr`.